# JPA: From entities, query other entities with no relational mapping between them

Tags: jpa

My question is probably so simple, that I can't find an answer for it.

I want to do something like this:

```
@Entity  
public class EntityA {

    @Transient
    @SomeQueryAnnotation(query="select b from EntityB where b.id=1")
    private EntityB entityB;
}
```

EntityB is kind of static resource. It should not be saved back to the database. There is also no mapping between the entities.

**[EDIT]**

Do you think it was ok, when I do this:

```
@Entity  
public class EntityA {

    private EntityB getEntityB() {
       ServiceRemote service = (ServiceRemote)context.lookup("ejb:ServiceRemote"); 
       return service.getEntityB();
    }
}
```

Than it should still be possible to use remoting, because the connection can be configured in each clients' jndi.properties file. what is your prefered method when you need to access the database from your entities?

Comment: if there is no relation between the two entites, why would you make entity B part of entity A instead of fetching it on it's own? this smells either like a badly designed legacy schema or a questionable design decision.

Comment: Good question. EntityA acts like a plugin and extends the SuperEntity. But to do its job it needs to retrieve more data. This case is more an exception then the typical way of doing this.

Comment: Hmm, I have my doubts that JPA bends this way, but I'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

Best recommendation - Unless these objects have an in-database relation, then there shouldn't be an entity relationship.

Second best - I would recommend you create a data transfer object to fetch your object.

```
@Entity  
public class EntityA {

  @Transient
  private EntityB entityB;
}

@Stateless
public class EntityADTO {
   EntityManager em;

   public EntityA findA(Object pkey) {
      EntityA a = em.find(okey, EntityA.class);
      a.entityB = em.find(1, EntityB.class);

      return a;
   }
}
```